# How do I fetch user information to display in a feed of posts using firebase storage solutions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm building a forum-style application where users post content that displays on a global feed. I want to display information about the user in posts (photoURL, displayName) similar to Twitter.

I have firebase v9 using the authentication and firestore for the posts. The reason I want to reference the auth is that I can catch changes to the user's information as it happens, this way the feed is up to date.

I save the user's unique ID with the post so I am able to reference who to display. I can successfully reference the post title and description with `doc.title & doc.description` however I get stuck when retrieving user information. I'm trying `doc.UserID.displayName` for the display name but I know this is incorrect. I can't find anything in the docs for this specific use case, is this something that I can do with just firestore and auth?

Do I need to create a reference to the auth storage with `doc.UserID`?

Here is the code:

```
// add a new post
addPostForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        const colRef = collection(db, 'Posts');
        console.log(hiddenURL.value);
        addDoc(colRef, {
            UserID: user.uid,
            beatURL: hiddenURL.value,
            title: addPostForm.postTitle.value,
            description: addPostForm.postDescription.value,
        })
            .then(() => {
                console.log("Document written with ID: ", doc.id);
                addPostModal.classList.remove('open');
                addPostForm.querySelector('.error').textContent = "";
            })
            .catch(error => {
                addPostForm.querySelector('.error').textContent = error.message;
                alert(error);
            })
    })
});

export const initApp = async () => {
  initFirebaseAuth;

  const posts = await collection(db, 'Posts');
  // render data to the page
  return renderPosts(posts);
};

const renderPosts = (posts) => {
  const main = document.getElementById("feed");

  onSnapshot(posts, (snapshot) => {
    let cardsArray = []
    snapshot.docs.forEach((doc, user) => {
      cardsArray.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })

      name.textContent = `${doc.UserID.displayName}`; // users display name
      avatar.src = doc.UserID.photoURL; //user's image
      description.textContent = `${post.description}`;
      title.textContent = `${post.title}`; 

    });
    console.log(cardsArray);
  });
};
```

Comment: Can you share the complete code and a screenshot of your Firestore document? We cannot see where most of the variables are coming from. A [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) will help too.

Comment: Your users are only defined in the Auth service or you have, in parallel, a `users`collection that holds user's info (a classic pattern)?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I have edited and added the post function, I will work on a codesandbox too if necessary.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I do have a 'users' collection, but this just saves bookmarked posts currently. Should I use this for referencing user details? - If so how will it get updated when a profile photo or display name is changed etc, would I have to create a function to update this also - sounds like a large work around with a lot of read and writes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two cases and approaches at first sight:

##### 1. Your users profiles are only available in the Auth Service

In this case, via the JS SDK, a user X cannot "query" the Auth profile of a user Y.

This means that you need to save the author's `displayName` together with the author `uid` when the `post` is created.

##### 2. Your users profiles are also available in a `users` collection (a common pattern)

In this case, when you display a post, you could fetch the user's document to get the author's `displayName`.

**However**, in the NoSQL world, you should not be afraid to duplicate data and denormalize your data model. When designing your data-model you should think about it from a query perspective, trying to minimize the number of queries for a given screen/use case. **So approach #1 is recommended, even if you maintain a user's collection**.

In case of changes in the user's profile, in order to synchronyse the `post` documents and user's data a common approach is to use a set of [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) (which are executed in the back-end) to update the `post` documents. The link between the posts and the users profile being the user's `uid`.

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a great answer! I will get to implementing option 1 because it seems the best way to go. For the cloud function would I use onUpdate, to look for changes in User information? This will certainly get me busy for the next week, but really helpful thank you!

Comment: Yes for the cloud function of approach #2 an onUpdate is fine. For approach #1 note that if the user changes his displayName in the Auth service you cannot trigger a Cloud Function due to the limited types of trigger for the Auth service (creation and deletion only). So you’ll need to other update all the posts from the front-end or trigger a CF with another  way, e.g. call a Callable CF.

Comment: When you say - "update all the posts from the front-end" does that mean it's a manual process for the user? - if so that is not the desired UX.  For the Callable CF, what is the call? To read all the user's auth data before displaying the post in the feed? Are there any resources you can point to for this I'm a little out of my depth.

Comment: When you say - "update all the posts from the front-end" does that mean it's a manual process for the user?  => No, it's not manual. It means that if you call the JS SDK method to, for example, update the displayName of the user, you should call the Firetore JS SD method to update all the posts of the user. This is the approach from the **front-end** (not the best...)

Comment: The other approach is from the **back-end**. You use a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) to update all the posts where the user is the author. So, from the front-end, you call the JS SDK method to, for example, update the displayName of the user AND you call the Callable CF (Only 2 calls from the FE)

Comment: Excellent, thank you ever so much for clarifying. I have a good idea of how to approach this now. Hope you have a great week!